What is the biblically sound understanding of Genesis 2:2-3?
In Genesis 2:2-3 we are told:

2 And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made.
3 And God blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it: because that in it he had rested from all his work which God created and made.

Limiting the scope of the question — setting aside what it means that the seventh day of the week was "blessed" and "sanctified" by God — and focusing narrowly on the "longitudinal" impact of these verses, what is the biblically sound interpretation?
I was able to think of three possible options here (if you can think of another, please include it in your answer):

the only day that was blessed was the actual “historical” first Sabbath (with no other Sabbaths meant to enjoy the blessing that was given to that original /first and only/ seventh day);
every subsequent seventh day was blessed from the original Sabbath until a later point in time when that blessing was removed or modified by another divine decree (e.g., transferred to another day or limited in its scope to the ethnic Jews).
all subsequent Sabbaths were blessed;

What biblically based arguments do the various denominations give for their interpretation of this scripture?

jI havent bothered to read beyond the first part of the question...the rest is completely irrelevant given that we only know of the Sabbath because of Jewish tradition (ie it was the Jewish tradition that past the entire old testament on to us). It is very clear from Jewish tradition historically that the "Seventh Day" of the week is what is blessed. This type of question only promotes feeble attempts at rationalising why the Sabbath can be worshipped on Sunday and that then leads to Theistic Evolutionism where the entire creation account is not literal history.

Is this a good faith question or a Seventh Day Adventist polemic apology masquerading as a question? It honestly looks like the latter as written.

Romans 14:5 is relevant here: “ 5One person esteems one day as better than another, while another esteems all days alike. Each one should be fully convinced in his own mind.”

If someone would like to use Romans 14:5 to oppose the 4th Commandment and the 7th Day Sabbath it teaches believers to "remember" and "keep," the person would have to assert (and prove) two points: 1) that the Sabbath is part of "ceremonial" law (which it isn't based on the timing of its original impartation); and 2), that Paul is NOT talking about ceremonial law (that indeed was "fulfilled" by Christ on the cross) which it is clear that he does from the context of the chapter. If someone argues for the abolition of the 4th Commandment, they're arguing to abolish the other nine (James 2:10).

You seem to have made your mind up on this point, so I’m confused as to the purpose of your question unless your purpose is to present a polemic apology disguised as a question.

No individual or denomination has monopoly on truth. Someone who has a biblically sound view of the issue, can present it and let everyone judge it on its merits. I presented several viewpoints and pointed out strengths and weaknesses of each. If you disagree with my presentation of the issue, you can say so and propose an alternative take. While I do have strong convictions (as do you, it appears), they aren't so strong that they cannot be overcome by a biblically sound argument. Over the years I revised many of my previously-held beliefs, and am willing to do it again. I hope so can you...

I doubt this question will ever be reopened as long as the Title contains "What do you believe". Questions are required to be objective, without references to "I" or "you", and to generate objective answers.

I've added the explicit question at the end to help bring it more into what is required of a question here. It might need further changes, or feel free to roll back to the previous version.


for we do enter into the rest—we who did believe, as He said, 'So I sware in My anger, If they shall enter into My rest—;' and yet the works were done from the foundation of the world, for He spake in a certain place concerning the seventh day thus: 'And God did rest in the seventh day from all His works;' and in this place again, 'If they shall enter into My rest—;' since then, it remaineth for certain to enter into it, and those who did first hear good news entered not in because of unbelief— again He doth limit a certain day, 'To-day,' (in David saying, after so long a time,) as it hath been said, 'To-day, if His voice ye may hear, ye may not harden your hearts,' for if Joshua had given them rest, He would not concerning another day have spoken after these things; there doth remain, then, a sabbatic rest to the people of God, for he who did enter into his rest, he also rested from his works, as God from His own. - Hebrews 4:3-10 YLT

Hebrews chapters 3 and 4 develop another option and reveal the original purpose of the Sabbath.  Just as on the 7th day God rested from all His labors so are we, in Christ, to enter into that rest:  Not going about doing our own works but participating in the works that God prepared for us from the foundation of the world.
The Sabbath commandment is part of that which was given as a schoolmaster to bring us unto Christ.  Having come to Christ we no longer need the schoolmaster:  As Paul says, we are no longer under the Schoolmaster, the law.
This is heady stuff but if you will receive it, Christ is our Sabbath rest.  He is the finished work of God.  We do not strive to observe the Sabbath.  We strive to abide in Christ always and thereby in God's 7th day rest always.

Christ was "made unto us wisdom, and righteousness, and sanctification, and redemption" (1 Cor 1:30). Rest is not numbered here (even though rest is what Jesus does promise elsewhere). The issue is whether or not we as Christians are to "keep" the Sabbath as 4th Commandment teaches. If not, why not? If we are, then we have to somehow arrive at what that would look like on a weekly basis, and if it doesn't look like what the 4th Commandment clearly prescribes (observation of the 7th day Sabbath), then we have to come up with a biblical reason to rest on another day. What's that day and why it?

Yes, Mike, Jesus used the event of king David to show nit-picking sabattarian legalists that "the Son of man is Lord also of the sabbath" - he having been accused by those legalists of breaking their sabbath stipulations - Mark 2:23-28. The sabbath is all about the Lord of the Sabbath - Jesus Christ - for he is the only entry into God's true rest from our own works. It's not about us and doing (or not doing) anything on a particular day of the week; it's entering into peace with God by resting in faith in the finished work of Christ.

@onceDelivered In Christ it is every day all the time everywhere.

@MikeBorden Do you need to earn income on a weekly basis? I'm happy for you and Anne if you don't. I have a job, so I must work 6 days like most. If you do work 6 days to support yourself (and set aside a day for a special time of worship, fellowship, and Bible study), what day is it and why do you set aside that day? What is your biblical rationale for setting aside a day that is different from the one that God set aside in the beginning? And if the Jesus you believe in is both a Sabbath-breaker and a sinless Son of God, doesn't your theology have some internal inconsistency? I think it does.

Jesus Christ Himself shed a lot of light on this subject at Matthew 12:8, Luke 6:5, and Mark 2:27-28, where Jesus said, "And He was saying to them, The Sabbath was made for man, and not man for the Sabbath. "Consequently, the Son of Man is Lord even of the Sabbath."
The implication in Jesus' words is that this ought to have been discernible by anyone who had read and understood God's command in this regard, especially the exceptions found in the Old Testament.
Greek is able to distinguish between "man" as the make of the species, and "man" generically. The word here is the latter, "anthropos, meaning all humans. God did not create mankind for the purpose of observing the Sabbath. He created the Sabbath for the benefit of mankind.
Btw, Hebrews 4:9-10 backs this up. "There remains therefore a Sabbath rest for the people of God. Vs10, "For the one who has entered His rest has himself also rested from his works, as God did from His."
There is more here than meets the eye as it relates to "rest." God created the human race and placed it upon earth so He could maintain a unique relationship with those whom He had created in His own image. Gods rest certainly included a relationship with Him through His Son Jesus Christ who is identified as "The Lord of the Sabbath."

I dont think that addresses the question...the issue remains, "Are we required to keep the Seventh Day Sabbath?". The answer, according to Jewish tradition from where the Old Testament came to us, is a definite yes!

@adam Can provide a better answer using "Theistic Evolutionism?" Is the following what you believe? "The first boundary of theistic evolution states that there is a God, but He was not directly involved in the origin of life. According to this view, God created the building blocks and natural laws with the eventual emergence of life in mind. However, early on He stepped back and let His creation take over." I can see it now at Genesis 1:31 when, "God saw all that He had made and behold, it was very good." He then stepped back and "poof" all the building blocks came together on their own.

#1 (the only day that was blessed was the actual “historical” first Sabbath) is not supported by the Bible.
As argued in the Question.
#2 (blessed from the original Sabbath until modified by another divine decree) is not supported by the Bible.
Perhaps the strongest arguments against this position come from the Catholic Church itself.
The Church does believe that the sabbath was "modified by another divine decree",
but that the divine decree came through the Church, not from the Bible.
In Faith of our Fathers, James Cardinal Gibbons stated:

You may read the Bible from Genesis to Revelation, and you will not find a single line authorizing the sanctification of Sunday.
The Scriptures enforce the religious observance of Saturday, a day which we never sanctify.

The Catholic Virginian (3 October 1947) article, To Tell You The Truth stated:

Nowhere in the Bible do we find that Christ or the Apostles ordered that the Sabbath be changed from Saturday to Sunday.
We have the commandment of God given to Moses to keep holy the Sabbath day, that is the 7th day of the week, Saturday.

The Convert’s Catechism of Catholic Doctrine, 1957, contains questions and answers that must be memorized by the faithful:

Q: Which is the Sabbath day?
A: Saturday is the Sabbath day.
Q: Why do we observe Sunday instead of Saturday?
A: We observe Sunday instead of Saturday because the Catholic Church, in the Council of Laodicea, transferred the solemnity from Saturday to Sunday.

The Roman Church not only acknowledges that moving the sabbath from Saturday to Sunday was their own devising, but that it has no Biblical foundation whatsoever.
The Church regards the Pope as a higher authority than the Bible, so that the Church moved the solemnity of the day to Sunday is a self-consistent and reasonable belief.
The Church uses this fact to demonstrate how the Protestant churches that broke away from Rome still respect the Church's teaching.

"The Scriptures enforce the religious observance of Saturday",
"Nowhere in the Bible do we find that Christ or the Apostles ordered that the Sabbath be changed from Saturday to Sunday.,
"the Catholic Church, in the Council of Laodicea, transferred the solemnity from Saturday to Sunday.".

#3 (all subsequent Sabbaths were blessed) is definitely supported by the Bible, and by common logic.
The weekly sabbath is described not as something specifically for the Israelites, but as being the sabbath of God and holy to God:

But the seventh day is the sabbath of the LORD thy God …
— Exodus 20:10


Six days may work be done; but in the seventh is the sabbath of rest, holy to the LORD …
— Exodus 31:15

The weekly sabbath wasn't created for the Israelites, its existence since creation was revealed to them:

And madest known unto them thy holy sabbath … by the hand of Moses thy servant:
— Nehemiah 9:14

The weekly sabbath was created, but it was created for all mankind:

And [Jesus] said unto them, The sabbath was made for man, and not man for the sabbath:
— Mark 2:27


I think its pretty clear that given: 1. we only have the Old Testament because of Jewish tradition, 2. Moses spoke face to face with God who obviously doesnt have memory problems in explaining which day of the week the Sabbath falls on 3. The Seventh Day is specifically a celebration of the end of creation and our creator, 4. The Sabbath command predates the entry of sin into this world and therefore the claim for worshipping the resurrection (on Sunday) has nothing to do with the Sabbath at all...Samuel got things pretty right when he said to King Saul "to obey is better than to sacrifice.
